# Undeleting answers deleted by former moderator

Tags: bug, moderators, vote-to-undelete

If a moderator has deleted a post, users are not able to cast undelete votes on it. They will receive the following error:

[image]

However, if a post was deleted by someone who is *no longer a moderator*, users with more than 20k+ reputation can cast undelete votes on it. For example, [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19874/51379), deleted by a former Science Fiction and Fantasy moderator:

[image]

Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: @Laurel - It seems like exactly the opposite case, though it may very well stem from the same code: evaluating actions based on the current status of a user, rather than the status at the time they took those actions.

Comment: If you read til the end, it mentions the reverse scenario too.

Comment: @Laurel - Ah, so it does.

Comment: @Laurel - That said, it seems that that behavior still hasn't been fixed, three years later!